# In std::map, how to write allocator to accept the key as the value's constructor argument?

Tags: c++

For example:

```
#include <map>
class A {
 public:
  A(int i) {}
};

std::map<int, A> as;

int main() {
  A& a = as[1];
}
```

This code will of cause not compile because the `A` do not have a default constructor.

So how to (or can I?) write an allocator, which will create an `A` by using `1` as the constructor parameter?

Comment: Wouldn't it be much simpler to use [`emplace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace)? Or [`try_emplace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/try_emplace) if you are using C++17?

Comment: Alternatively, if you must use index, you can use `A &a = as.at(1);`

Comment: @UnholySheep because I *won't* emplace if `as[1]` exists.

Comment: `emplace` doesn't emplace if the element already exists: *"Inserts a new element into the container constructed in-place with the given args **if there is no element with the key in the container.**"* - the first line of the documentation I linked in my comment

Comment: Allocators do not construct objects, they allocate memory (the construct member is deprecated in C++17 and removed in C++20). `std::map::operator[]` requires that the value is default-constructible, no fiddling with allocators will change that.

Comment: @UnholySheep another reason is that get the value from what returned from emplace is tediously, I want the map easy to use to others.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Maybe you could make your comment as an answer, simply a "No, you can't, here's why", I like it.

Comment: I'm sorry I was wrong, C++17 simply uses `allocator_traits<T>::construct`, if you specialise it then you might be able to do what you want with allocators.

Comment: I just tried it and it is extremely hard to make it work because, unlike other containers, `std::map` calls placement new on the node type (pair) and the value constructor *separately* from the allocator policy. Maybe it could work with other map-like containers like `flat-map` https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/doc/html/boost/container/flat_map.html but I wouldn't hold my breath.  Here it is my incomplete attempt: https://godbolt.org/z/jc34dn

Finally, remember Stepanov's words: *" "people who write [value] class without a default constructor deserve what they get."*.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a wrapper for [`try_emplace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/try_emplace) that tries to emplace a new `A` element at a given key (if it does not exist) using the value of the key as the `try_emplace` forwading argument. You can combine structured bindings within initialization statements in `if` statements to somewhat neatly either get the newly inserted element or access to the pre-existing one.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <utility>

struct A {
  A(int i) : i_(i) {}
  int i_;
};

template <typename Key>
auto try_emplace_key_as_arg(std::map<Key, A> &m, Key &&key) {
  return m.try_emplace(key, std::forward<Key>(key));
}

template <typename Key>
void try_emplace_with_diagnostics(std::map<Key, A> &m, Key &&key) {
  if (auto [it, was_inserted] =
          try_emplace_key_as_arg(m, std::forward<Key>(key));
      was_inserted) {
    std::cout << "\nNew: " << it->second.i_;
  } else {
    std::cout << "\nAlready existed: " << it->second.i_;
  }
}

int main() {
  std::map<int, A> as{{2, A{2}}};
  try_emplace_with_diagnostics(as, 1); // New: 1
  try_emplace_with_diagnostics(as, 2); // Already existed: 2
}
```